SQLAlchemy create_all() doesn't create tables
I'm trying to create a set of tables using SQLAlchemy 2.0
import logging
import logging.handlers

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s [%(name)-5s] [%(levelname)-3s] %(message)s'
)

from typing import List, Dict
# from DAL.database import Report, Database
import util.utility as util

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, DateTime, func, exc
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker, Mapped, DeclarativeBase, mapped_column
from datetime import datetime

config: Dict = util.read_config("../static/configurations/custom.yaml")

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Attribute_Details(Base):
    """

    """
    __tablename__ = "attribute_details"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    opened: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    closed: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column()
    report_attr: Mapped["Report_Attributes"] = relationship(back_populates="details")


class Database:
    """
    Abstraction layer for the SQLAlchemy db interface
    """

    meta: MetaData
    engine: Engine
    session_maker: sessionmaker
    __connected: bool = False

    tables: List[Base] = [Attribute_Details]

    def __init__(self, con_str: str):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(Database.__name__)
        self.logger.info("Connecting to DB: {}".format(con_str))
    
        self.db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(con_str, echo=False)

    def connect(self) -> bool:
        """
        Establish connection to the database
        """
        try:
            self.engine = self.db.connect()
            self.session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
            self.meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
            return True
        except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
            print(str(e))
            return False


    def create_tables(self):
        """
        Create the corresponding tables for the Report template
        """
        for table in self.tables:
            if not self.engine.dialect.has_table(self.engine, table.__tablename__):
                table_obj = [table.__table__]
                Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine, tables=table_obj)
                # CreateTable(table_obj).compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect())
                self.logger.info("Created DB Table {}".format(table.__tablename__))
            else:
                self.logger.info("DB Table {} already exists".format(table.__tablename__))


db = Database(config['db_con_test'])
db.connect()
db.create_tables()

Although it reports "Created DB Table attribute_details", the table is not created in the database. I tried the option with Base.metadata.create_all() as well as CreateTable(). I cannot spot the issue as the creation of tables with the new Declarative Mapping of SQL2.0 isn't explained very well... at least for me.

Please edit the question to provide a [mre]. For example connect and create_tables are class methods but they're not in a class in your question. After making the changes needed to get the code to run I could not reproduce the problem.

Updated the code to a complete MVE (beside the fact that you need a postgresql db), but still no table is created. Is there a way to get more information on the reason why Alchemy didn't create the table?

Your self.engine is not an Engine object, it is a Connection object. Apparently when .create_all() is passed a Connection it assumes that you have accepted responsibility for transaction handling, so it emits the CREATE TABLE statement on that Connection but does not commit (because that's your job). I would suggest that you not use the names self.db for your Engine object and self.engine for your Connection object — it's just too confusing.

"Is there a way to get more information on the reason why Alchemy didn't create the table?" — Using echo=True or echo="debug" when calling create_engine() is often helpful.

@GordThompson, do you want to post an answer? Your input regarding mixup of connection and engine was correct.

The typical usage is to call .create_all() with an Engine object.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "thing"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    description: Mapped[str]


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
"""
CREATE TABLE thing (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    description VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2024-06-12 06:37:19,592 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00018s] ()
2024-06-12 06:37:19,592 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT

Process finished with exit code 0
"""

Apparently when .create_all() is passed a Connection it assumes that you have accepted responsibility for transaction handling, so it emits the CREATE TABLE statement on that Connection but does not commit (because that's your job).
engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
conn = engine.connect()
Base.metadata.create_all(conn)
"""
CREATE TABLE thing (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    description VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2024-06-12 06:42:01,819 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00024s] ()

Process finished with exit code 0
"""

However if we use a context manager (as recommended for SQLAlchemy 2+), then that can also make the commit happen. .create_all() does not do the commit, but the context manager does.
engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
with engine.begin() as conn:  # "begin once" pattern
    Base.metadata.create_all(conn)
    """
CREATE TABLE thing (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    description VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2024-06-12 06:46:09,601 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00027s] ()
2024-06-12 06:46:09,601 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT

Process finished with exit code 0
    """

